# JQueryUI Draggable: TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, html5-draggable

I'm trying to attach JQueryUI draggable to a set of elements below:

```
                            <ul class="children">
                                <li id="component-nav" class="component-palette-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i><span> Navigation</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="component-container" class="component-palette-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-file-text-o"></i><span> Container</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="component-row" class="component-palette-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-list" ></i><span> Row</span></a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="component-column" class="component-palette-item"><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-columns"></i><span> Column</span></a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
```

The draggable initialization code:

```
$('.component-palette-item').draggable({
        containment: designPanel,
        helper: 'clone',
        cursor: "move"
    });
```

The element is displayed as below:

[image]

As soon as I mouse down to click on one of the items, I get this error on Firefox:

```
TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.
```

The browser become suspended churning out multiple error above every time I move the mouse and the clicked element becomes like this. This is before any dragging can be performed.

[image]

Comment: FF and draggable have a bit of a history with each other. I think you are seeing an incarnation of [this known issue](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/10725).

Comment: I followed the whole stack by stepping on the debugger for 30 mins. I discovered that there is a infinite recursion: return window.getComputedStyle( elem, null ); that is possibly causing the error.